# Is there a way to automate this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

[enter image description here][1]

I need to find the hour wise %contribution for each state.I used =$G20/SUM($G$20:$G$23) to calculate for each hour. Is there a way to do this for all hours using a single formula?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwo7S.png

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Excel 2010 if array-entered with the range D2:D19 highlighted:

```
=C2:C19/SUMIF(A2:A19,A2:A19,C2:C19)
```

Or as a pull-down formula starting in D2:

```
=C2/SUMIF(A$2:A$19,A2,C$2:C$19)
```

Tested in Excel 365:

[image]